# DiffBind: Model must include count data for contrasts.

Tags: atac-seq

I am trying to use `DiffBind` for my `ATACseq` experiment going through the `vignette` for `DiffBind`. I was able to import the data and make a heatmap with `plot(data)`. But somehow calling `data <- dba.contrast(data, categories=DBA_TISSUE)` function is not working for me giving a warning message:

> Warning message:
>   Model must include count data for contrasts.

I tried running beforehand: `data <- dba.count(data)` but it is giving an error:

> Error: Error processing one or more read files. Check warnings().
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1:
>   2:
>   3:
>   4:
>   5:
>   6:
>   7:

My `sample_sheet.csv`looks like that:

[image]

I just need to compare `Dura` vs `Microglia` which is `Tissue` column. How could this error be fixed? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that you have a BED file in the bamReads column rather than the BAM file that you fed to MACS2...

Comment: I know but it is written in the documentation that both bed and bam files are fine. I tried supplying bam files too since I have them, but it does not work either.

Comment: Sure it can accept BED files, but they need to be from something like `bedtools bamtobed`. What was the error when you used BAM files?

Comment: Wrong suffix error and just empty warnings as shown at the top. My data quality is poor (low mapping rates), so can it just be data quality issue?

Comment: Could be. You might try CSAW instead, it's what we use for differential accessibility with ATAC-seq data.

Comment: Can you provide some reproducible data to test and see how to avoid the error?

Comment: With the data that I have now it is definitely not working, and the issue is not yet solved either because of the poor quality data, or because something else is going wrong. I will post the answer if I figure out why that was happening. Besides, I am not sure how I can attach `12` files here, or even just `2` for `1` sample.

Comment: Ah, I have definitely run into this issue before - it is resolveable, but I cannot for the life of me remember exactly what the issue was. I think it was related to the file paths, but your data quality is likely not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using wrong files. I ran a pipeline from [here](http://code.databio.org/PEPATAC/) and it generates several folders with many files. The `.bam` files that should be used are located in the `aligned_mm10` folder and are with the extension: `.pe.q10.sort.rmdup.bam`.

Comment: This link leads to a page not found. What was the pipeline that you were using?

Comment: I see, it is just a `private` page, so that is why you might not be able to access it. It is this one: https://github.com/databio look for `pepatac`. Then, my answer is useless since no one can access it anyway...